# How to Get addresses from postalcode as like royalmail find-a-postcode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

My question is:
How to Get addresses from postalcode as like royalmail find-a-postcode ?

For this i have created a demo page and did lots of R&D but not getting any scussess.
YOu can check the demo page and royal mail site and enter postalcode "HA5 1AA"

http://www.gibbs-gillespie.co.uk/zipcodeaddress.html

https://www.royalmail.com/find-a-postcode

Where royal mail return 5 result and google return only one result.

Please give me the solution or some hint

Thanks

Comment: To me what you are actually asking here is unclear. No context. No code. Just a vague comparison between a postal service and Google maps with a link. What is the issue upon which I can try to suggest a solution?

Comment: `zip-address-location.html:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your code and some found aboard the mighty Google Mothership I think this ought to help get you going.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <head>
        <title>Geocode address - find Postcode</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <style type='text/css'>
            body {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 10pt;
            }
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
            html, body {
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #latlng {
                width: 225px;
            }
            #container{
                display:block;  
                height:500px;
                width:500px;
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            #data{
                width:100%;
                height:2rem;
                padding:1rem;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                display:block;
            }
            #txtPlaces{
                width:100%;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                padding:1rem;
                margin:0 auto 1rem auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDsCn5YSPGtKhk3RiU2svNV5GKEEMJc84I&libraries=places'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            (function(){

                var map,infowindow,lat,lng,geocoder,data;
                var place,address,geometry,marker,content;

                function initMap() {
                    /* default location */
                    lat=53.971481395939115;
                    lng=-3.439286750000065;


                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        zoom: 5,
                        center: { lat:lat, lng:lng }
                    });
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point( 0, -32 )
                    });

                    content=document.getElementById('content');
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                    infowindow.setContent( content );

                    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( document.getElementById('txtPlaces') );

                    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map );
                    marker.setVisible( false );

                    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                        infowindow.close();
                        place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                        if( !place.geometry ) {
                            alert( 'Bad foo: '+place.name );
                            return false;
                        }

                        if( place.geometry.viewport ) {
                            map.fitBounds( place.geometry.viewport );
                        } else {
                            map.setCenter( place.geometry.location );
                            map.setZoom(15);
                        }
                        marker.setPosition( place.geometry.location );
                        marker.setVisible( true );

                        address = '';
                        if( place.address_components ) {
                            address = [
                                ( place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || '' ),
                                ( place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || '' ),
                                ( place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '' ),
                                ( place.address_components[3] && place.address_components[3].short_name || '' ),
                                ( place.address_components[4] && place.address_components[4].short_name || '' ),
                                ( place.address_components[5] && place.address_components[5].short_name || '' )
                            ].join( ' ' );
                        }

                        content.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
                        content.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
                        content.children['place-address'].textContent = address;

                        infowindow.open( map, marker );
                        geocodeLatLng( geocoder );
                    });
                }

                function geocodeLatLng( geocoder ) {
                    address=document.getElementById('txtPlaces').value;
                    data = document.getElementById('data');

                    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function( results, status ) {
                        if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                            if ( results[0] ) {
                                geometry=results[0].geometry.location;
                                latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( geometry.lat(), geometry.lng() );
                                map.setZoom( 17 );
                                map.setCenter( latlng );
                                data.innerHTML=results[0].formatted_address;
                            } else {
                                window.alert('No results found');
                            }
                        } else {
                            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                        }
                    });
                }

                document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', initMap, false );
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Location:</h1>
        <div id='content'>
            <img src='' width='16' height='16' id='place-icon'>
            <span id='place-name' class='title'></span><br>
            <span id='place-address'></span>
        </div>

        <div id='container'>
            <input type='text' id='txtPlaces' placeholder='Enter a location' />
            <div id='map'></div>
            <span id='data'></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mistakenly i mentioned wrong url. The url is: http://www.gibbs-gillespie.co.uk/zipcodeaddress.html and i want 5 results instead of one. google return only one result where as royalmail return 5 results

Comment: But the PostOffice are not using Google APIs to deliver their results so you can only work within the bounds of what Google deliver. There is, for the UK anyway, a freely available database of all ( ? ) UK postcodes - you could perhaps incorporate that if you are doing searches in the UK but otherwise I cannot, off the top of my head, think of a way around the limitations of the google api.

Comment: Incidentally: `zipcodeaddress.html:173 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: You could perhaps tap into the PostOffice data - they have a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header so you should be able to send requests to it

Answer (score 0):

To add a postcode finder just like Royal Mail's solution, you'll need to procure a  license from a PAF solutions provider. Royal Mail provides a much more accurate and up-to-date address list than Google Places.

In the UK, there are a few suppliers; here's a list: https://www.poweredbypaf.com/using-our-address-data/find-a-ready-made-solution/.

[Ideal Postcodes](https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk/postcode-lookup) is one supplier that offers postcode lookup + additional datasets. For example, the [multiple residence dataset](https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk/guides/multiple-residence) captures sub-premises situated within multiple occupancy buildings which do not have their own publicly available delivery point (e.g., one letterbox, mailing point, etc.). This is why you might see more addresses in Royal Mail's postcode finder than Google's solution.